# How did Demegawa and Kira communicate in Death Note?

Tags: death-note

In the latter part of the Death Note anime, and manga, Kira begins communicating with his followers to give them instructions.

One such instruction is to his "evangelist" Demegawa.

> After Near takes over the investigations Light finds out about the existence of the SPK in America, he sends Demegawa and a mob of Kira worshipers to a building in New Your City to pull Near and the others in front of TV cameras so Misa can kill them with the Death Note.

The instructions were specific enough to get a mob of people to converge on an address at the same time.  I'm guessing Demegawa wouldn't have shown up without some reasonably detailed communication.

Comment: Afair, there wasn't any direct communication. ... or maybe it was through takada. hmmmm....